# Which visa and/or work permit do I need to enter and work in Germany as a foreign researcher?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I accepted an offer for a three-year postdoc in Germany. It is not clear to me if I need to apply for a work permit/EU Blue Card in addition to my researcher visa. Where can I learn more? (Or do I wait for my institution to advise me on the next steps.) I don't speak German.

Comment: This will depend on the contract between you and the institution. **Research only** (*Residence for research purposesor*) or  **Research and employment** (*Residence for employment*): [BAMF - Bundesamt für Migration und Flüchtlinge - Scientists](https://www.bamf.de/EN/Themen/MigrationAufenthalt/ZuwandererDrittstaaten/Arbeit/Wissenschaftler/wissenschaftler-node.html).

Comment: It is pretty probable that your institution will advise you in detail, but you can of course always ask them, as they probably would be the most qualified in your case.